# Codeigniter pagination do not work properly

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I use codeigntier 3 pagination library.

It works, but not exactly how should.

First I will post my code.

**controller setting**

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url('items');
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->ItemsM->countAll();
            $config['per_page'] = 5;
            $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
            $config['nex_link'] = "Next";

            $limit = $config['per_page'];
            $offset = $this->uri->segment(2);

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);


            $data = array(
                'musicians' => $this->ItemsM->allItems($limit, $offset),
                'pagination' => $this->pagination->create_links()
            );

            $this->load->view('public/header');
            $this->load->view('public/item-list', $data);
            $this->load->view("public/footer");
```

**Model**

class ItemsM extends CI_MODEL{

```
function allUsers($limit="", $offset ="")
{
    $query = $this->db->select('*')
                    ->from('items')
                    ->limit($limit)
                    ->offset($offset)
                    ->order_by('creation_date', 'desc')
                    ->get();

    return $query->result();
}

public function countAll(){
    return $this->db->count_all_results('items');
}
```

**Route**

```
$route['items/(:any)'] = 'items';
```

This pagination works, but the results Im getting are not correct.

On the first page/tab it shows items with this order

item 1 
 item 2 
 item 3 
 item 4 
 item 5 // ok

but when open page 2

I get next 5 results this way

item 3 
item 4 
item 5 
item 6 
item 7

Honestly I do not understand where is the problem, I someone know, please help. Thank you.

Comment: it seems like the problem is with your sql query. When you click on page 2 or next page you are getting results with offset 2. Means you are passing `$offset` as page number. Which is showing results after id 2 or after skipping 2 results. Right ?

Comment: It is more like repeating 3 results from page 1 on the page 2

Comment: yeah, in page 2 it starts from item3 because it is skipping first 2 results.

Comment: just try code of my answer which i just posted, hope that will work perfectly. If you face issues let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your problem is with varialble `$offset` as you are passing `$offset` as your page number for eg. if your page number is 2 then it will skip 2 results but you need to skip 5 results. To solve this replace this code with you controller setting.

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url('items');
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->ItemsM->countAll();
        $config['per_page'] = 5;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['nex_link'] = "Next";

        $limit = $config['per_page'];

        $page = $this->uri->segment(2);

        if($page > 1){
           $offset = ($page-1) * $limit;
        }else{
           $offset = $page;
           // Or you can set $offset = 0;
        }

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);


        $data = array(
            'musicians' => $this->ItemsM->allItems($limit, $offset),
            'pagination' => $this->pagination->create_links()
        );

        $this->load->view('public/header');
        $this->load->view('public/item-list', $data);
        $this->load->view("public/footer");
```

Here i edited your variable `$offset`. Now you will get results as expected.

Comment: Hm I tried, it runs good good on page, 2, 3 etc... but in page 1 getting sql syntax  error like this SELECT * FROM `items` LIMIT -5, 5...

Comment: oh, for that need to use if statement, just a sec..i will update answer

Comment: Welcome bro, Anytime

Comment: Perfect. Good job.